# MailEnable Intermittent 421 please try again later

Tags: email

We've been experiencing an intermittent connectivity issue with MailEnable. The STMP server seems to be refusing connections psuedo-randomly. For example:

```
telnet mail.ourdomain.com 25
```

Most of the time, the mail server responds with the proper greeting, but approximately 1 in 5 times, we receive this:

```
421 please try again later
```

And nothing else. Nothing in any of the log files indicates that this connection was received, or denied. Trying again immediately usually works.

Elsewhere, it has been suggested that increasing the maximum number of concurrent SMTP connections might resolve the issue. We've increased this number from 100 to 1000 with no effect.

Server Information:
 - MailEnable Standard Edition, v7.53
 - IIS v7.5.7600
 - Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Any suggestions for actions to take/try would be appreciated.

---

**Update**

Further investigation revealed that our mail server (hosted at a remote location) was the target of a brute force attack. We have since closed port 25, and required that all users use TLS/SSL instead.